# Filtering rows if the text (string) match in Dax

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop, measure

How to filter `my.data` if `my.data[column]` contains `"ABC"` in DAX. Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Measure = CALCULATE(COUNTROWS('my data'), FILTER('my data', SEARCH("abc", 'my data'[column],1,BLANK()) >0))
```

[image]